# Why is $x_1 x_2$ quasi-concave on $\mathbb{R}^2_+$?

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

I'm having trouble figuring out how to prove that $g(x)=x_1x_2$ is quasi-concave on $\mathbb{R}^2_+$. According to Steven Boyd's book this is trivial because the superlevel sets of $g(x)$ are clearly convex. Can anyone help me understand why this function is quasi-convex?

Comment: The set $\{x_1x_2<a\}\subset \mathbb{R}_+^2$ is the 'inside' of the hyperbola $x_1x_2=a$ in the first quadrant.

Comment: @EEE I see. Is there some way to prove that the inside of the hyperbola is convex?

Comment: I think that one solution would be to say that $x_1 x_2$ is log-concave on $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ (assuming $\log{0}=-\infty$) which implies quasi-concavity. I'm really wondering if there's a more direct way show that the superlevel sets are convex as Boyd has stated.

Comment: The second derivative of $a/x_2$ is $2a/x_2^3>0$ for $a,x_2>0$.

Comment: you can prove by the definition that the superlevel sets of f are convex using the definition of a convex set. $x_1y_1,  x_2y_2 \geq c $ implies their convex combination $\geq c$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to prove this is to use the fact that for any concave function $u$ and any increasing function $f$, the composition $f\circ u$ is quasi-concave. Indeed, the superlevel sets of $f\circ u$ are just super-level sets of $u$ (for a different level value).

In your case, $x_1x_2 = \exp(\log x_1 + \log x_2)$ and the function $\log x_1 + \log x_2$ is concave, being the sum of two concave functions.